# Is complacent a positive word or negative word?

Tags: expressions

When is complacent used in a positive or a negative sense?

I always thought it was used in a negative sense, please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: It often carries a negative sense, and never afaik carries a positive one. But it can simply refer to a conservative attitude toward change -- "If it works, don't fix it".

Comment: what about??
Despite having his job assured, Seager is far from complacent.

Comment: @Raghav That's certainly a negative sense for the word, since the positive sense is acheived by explicitly negating it with the "far from".

Answer (score 1):

If there *were* a way to interpret ***"complacency"*** in a positive sense, I would see it as an almost serendipitous by-product of a lack of action, for example:

> Due to Carol's ***"complacency"*** about making changes to her 401K account, the market eventually improved and her account showed a tidy net increase this year.